# C++ : List Seg Fault

Tags: c++, list, push-back

*Can anyone explain me why does this happened?*

When I call member function printEvent() inside the block of if-else,I get the correct output,but when I call printEvent() after the block I get this unknown result.

```
        list<Event*> currentEvents;
    for (j=1; j <= eventsNum; ++j)
    {   
        Event * newEvent;

        if (isIndividual(inFile)) {
            IndividualEvent newIndi = returnIndi(inFile);
            newEvent = &(newIndi);
            newEvent->printEvent();
        }else {
            TeamEvent newTeam = returnTeam(inFile);
            newEvent = &(newTeam);
            newEvent->printEvent();
        }
        cout << "WHY?" << endl;
        newEvent->printEvent();


        currentEvents.push_back(newEvent);
    }
    TVNode.push_back(newEmission);
}
```

***OUTPUT***

```
<Filiko1>
WHY HERE?
<Filiko1q<15-06-2015,14:00<Athens<0`W                                             ����Athensq<Football<1<0>!0����Footballq<2q<Olympiakos<PSG!
                                                                     ����OlympiakosxW^��DW����PSG^��DWPW�^��DWi�n
```

***The above code is part of a big exercise!***

Comment: After leaving the if clause scope `newEvent` points to an object that was on the stack and has been destroyed.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem ? Thanks for your time:)

Comment: If you're storing derived objects of different types in a list you should use `list<unique_ptr<Event>>` and then add then to the list like `currentEvents.push_back(unique_ptr<Event>(new IndividualEvent(returnIndi(inFile))));` etc.

Comment: Do you really, really need to have a vector of pointers? This is really asking for trouble.

Comment: I use a list of pointer because I want to store multiple derived classes types into the same list.Is there any safer way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The `newEvent` after if or else block points to already destructed object, as the object's lifetime is limited by the scope in which it is defined. In your case objects `newIndi` and `newTeam` will be destroyed after if-else statement, while `newEvent` pointer still points at one of them.

See this link to learn about C++ scopes: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: Limiting your answer to just this issue will inevitably lead to another question from the OP regarding the slicing problem...

Comment: @JonathanPotter True. I didn't read until the `push_back` part actually.